# Some pictures in web part are not visible?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Could anyone help me to fix an issue: In the web part, some of the pictures are shown but some of the pictures are not shown. Some users have their images in the system (like in Delve and in Skype), but they are not shown in the intranet pages. If I put mouse over the person, the picture is visible, but as normally I can't see their pictures. What can be a problem and how to fix it?